# Is there a way to have SQL SELECT a column with a different date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to pull a pretty simple report that reviews the last day's data. It looks similar to this:

```
SELECT Name, Date, Count
FROM dbo.X
WHERE Date BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -1, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DD, 0, GETDATE())
```

This works fine, but I've been asked to have a column present that shows **day before** count as well for comparison. I'm not really sure how to do this since the datetime condition is already specifying the last day. Is there a way to make this work so the select list would look like this for example?

```
SELECT Name, Date, YesterdaysCount, Count
```

Edit: Sample Data:

```
Name    Date    Count
a   6/22/2020   1
b   6/22/2020   2
c   6/22/2020   3
d   6/22/2020   4
e   6/22/2020   5
a   6/21/2020   2
b   6/21/2020   4
c   6/21/2020   6
d   6/21/2020   8
e   6/21/2020   10
```

Desired Results:

```
Name    Date    YesterdayCount  Count
a   6/22/2020   2   1
b   6/22/2020   4   2
c   6/22/2020   6   3
d   6/22/2020   8   4
e   6/22/2020   10  5
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you don't have a time component.  If you do, just change the "Y.[Date] =" to a BETWEEN as with the first part.

```
SELECT [Name], [Date], [Count], 
   (SELECT SUM(Y.[Count]) FROM dbo.X AS Y WHERE Y.[Name] = X.[Name] AND Y.[Date] = DATEADD(DAY, -1, X.[DATE]) AS YesterdaysCount
FROM dbo.X
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,-1,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DD, 0, GETDATE())
```

Comment: For consistency with the post, I kept in "DATEADD(dd, 0, GETDATE())" even though I know it's equivalent to just saying "GETDATE()"

Comment: Returned the following error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I do have a time component, sorry for not including that.

Comment: I added a "SUM" around the Y.[Count] in the sub-select, but the original question gave the impression that name / date / count was unique within the table.  If the question meant to show a row count with COUNT(*) instead, then the query I posted above would need to be modified a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, these are two ways.
I would suggest use variables for each day
if you only care about the day, i would recommend using date instead of datetime that way searching is faster (both variables, and casting your date field)

```
declare @table1 table (name varchar(10), YourDate datetime, YourCount int ) 

insert into @table1 values ('name1', '2020-06-19', 1)
--insert into @table1 values ('name1', '2020-06-20', 1)
insert into @table1 values ('name1', '2020-06-21', 2)
insert into @table1 values ('name1', '2020-06-22', 3)
insert into @table1 values ('name1', '2020-06-23', 4)
insert into @table1 values ('name1', '2020-06-24', 5)

--use date fiels for faster comparisson
declare @Today date=getdate(), @Yesterday date=dateadd(day,-1,getdate())

--using a left join to the same table for yesterdays (check for nulls)
SELECT t1.Name, t1.YourDate, 
    sum(isnull(t2.YourCount,0)) as YesterdayCount,
    sum(isnull(t1.YourCount,0)) as TodayCount
From @table1 t1
Left Join @table1 t2  on t1.name=t2.name and t2.YourDate=cast(dateadd(day,-1,t1.YourDate) as date)
Where cast(t1.YourDate as date) BETWEEN @Yesterday AND @Today
Group By t1.name, t1.YourDate

--using outer apply
SELECT t1.Name, t1.YourDate, 
    sum(isnull(t2.YourCount,0)) as YesterdayCount,
    sum(isnull(t1.YourCount,0)) as TodayCount
From @table1 t1
outer apply(
    Select t3.YourCount From @table1 t3 where t3.YourDate=cast(dateadd(day,-1,t1.YourDate) as date)
) as t2
Where cast(t1.YourDate as date) BETWEEN @Yesterday AND @Today
Group By t1.name, t1.YourDate
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
    Name, Date,
    (SELECT Count 
     WHERE Date BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -2, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DD, -1, GETDATE())) AS YesterdaysCount, Count
FROM
    dbo.X
WHERE
    Date BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -1, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DD, 0, GETDATE())
```